# Is Dapper query executed in QuerySingle one transaction?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, .net-core, dapper

Does dapper execute all query statements which are part of one query in QuerySingle method as one transaction?
Example

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE ...
INSERT INTO TABLE...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are responsible to create and manage the transaction. So if the second insert fails, the first insert will still be inserted if you don't use a transaction.

You can find how to use a transaction here:

- https://dapper-tutorial.net/transaction